# JPanel - Window with buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

this is basic example I got for a GUI from a book called Java In Easy Steps, I implemented the code as per the example but the imagery does not appear. What do I need to do in order to make it appear, is because of the URL getClassLoader?

Ideally I would like to be able to save a file to my workspace and use that file as a part of the GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Buttons extends JFrame {

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon tick = new ImageIcon("tickURL");
    ImageIcon cross = new ImageIcon("crossURL");

    JButton btn = new JButton("Click Me");
    JButton tickBtn = new JButton(tick);
    JButton crossBtn = new JButton("STOP", cross);

    ClassLoader ldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    java.net.URL tickURL = ldr.getResource("tick.png");
    java.net.URL crossURL = ldr.getResource("cross.png");

    public Buttons(){

        super("Swing Window");
        setSize( 500, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(pnl);
        setVisible(true);

        pnl.add(btn);
        pnl.add(tickBtn);
        pnl.add(crossBtn);

    }

    public static void main(String[]Args){

        Buttons gui = new Buttons();

    }

}
```

Comment: While editing, highlight the text you want to be a code sample and press CTRL+K.

Comment: If your book about GUIs shows examples where the GUI code is not invoked on the EDT, I would quickly throw the book away and switch to the Swing tutorials instead.

Comment: Java In Easy Steps was published in 2001.  You might as well be learning Cobol.  Switch to the Swing tutorials.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClassLoader ldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
java.net.URL tickURL = ldr.getResource("tick.png");
java.net.URL crossURL = ldr.getResource("cross.png");

JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
ImageIcon tick = new ImageIcon(tickURL);     // <-- a URL is needed here, not a string
ImageIcon cross = new ImageIcon(crossURL);   // same here

JButton btn = new JButton("Click Me");
JButton tickBtn = new JButton(tick);
JButton crossBtn = new JButton("STOP", cross);
```

1. load your assets with the classLoader (if they are in your classpath),
2. create your icons with these assets,
3. create your buttons with these icons

As simple as that.

Comment: @HopelessProgrammer  What do you mean by 'filepaths'?  Is that a poorly capitalized class name, or did you forget to add a space?

Comment: You can use a filepath in the getResource() method, which should match your classpath (ie "gfx/tick.png" if the image is in the gfx package). If you want a filepath to an external file, don't use the classLoader, just a File object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Java newbie and was plowing through the same code from the same book, with the same bad results (no icons appear for either block of code).  For the clueless (like moi) the book seemed to be saying that these two icons were available as part of a Java default package, which of course is not true.

The answer is that these two .png files were included in a download available for the book and the author assumed you had downloaded the files into the current directory, so the code would see them.

So both methods described above do indeed work when the icons are available.

The downloads are available here:  http://ineasysteps.com/resource-centre/downloads/